# How to create a unique table that is linked to another table?

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a project in Django. I want to create a column that will hold a list of activities (sports, educational etc. and each with a unique id and a name) that the user took part in.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an activities table containing all of the possible activity names and an intermediate table called UserActivities which connects the built in django User model to Activities. Also we make sure we can't have a repetitive UserActivities by invoking unique together. You could make the Activities model's primary key the name but I tend to stick will the auto id field.Hope this gets you started with django!

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Activities(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)


class UserActivities(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activities, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["user", "activity"]
```